How to allow background image overflow beyond viewport boundaries for elastic scrolling?
I’m trying to create a webpage where the background-image is larger than the viewport and allows for overflow in all directions when users pull the screen (for example, when using elastic scrolling). However, the default behavior is cropping the background image to the viewport size, causing white space when the user pulls the screen.
What I would like to achieve :
I want the elastic scrolling effect to reveal more of the background image instead of empty space.
Here’s a simplified example of what I have so far:
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            background-image: url("{% static 'base/media/background/test.jpg' %}");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

Can someone suggest a working example of this feature ?
Below an example of the white spaces that appear when pulling the screen (on this screenshot I'm pulling down left).

EDIT
It seems that the browser does not load what's outside the viewport explaining why it creates white spaces when I scroll beyond boundaries.
The only solution I found for now is to allowing scrolling (overflow: scroll;) and then to use javascript to automatically place the viewport in the middle of the image. From here I just disable scrolling with javascript (different from applying overflow: hidden;) and it display the desired effect. BUT it's buggy

Did you check in developer tools that if there is any padding or margin around the image. Also try to use width: 100%;

Yeah I checked everything, the image just get crop by the viewport dimensions. Not sure what I would like to realize is even possible
